# Contraction of only one of the indexes of a symmetric tensor with an antissymetric tensor is zero?

Tags: tensor-products, tensor-decomposition

So guys I was trying to show some expressions in general relativity and I have the contraction of two tensor objects, those being:

$$\sigma_{\mu\nu} = \sigma_{\nu\mu},$$

and,

$$\omega_{\mu\nu} = -\omega_{\nu\mu}.$$

The contraction of a symmetric object with an antissymetric one is zero, like this:

$$\sigma_{\alpha\beta}\omega^{\alpha\beta}=0.$$

The question is: "Can I also say that the following contraction is zero?"

$$\sigma_{\mu\beta}\omega^{\beta}_{\nu} = ?$$

Comment: You should be able to come up with easy counterexamples on a $2$-dimensional spacetime.

Comment: Do you mean like this:

$$\sigma_{\mu\beta}\omega^{\beta}_{\nu}=\sigma_{\mu 0}\omega^{0}_\nu+\sigma_{\mu 1}\omega^{1}_{\nu} + \sigma_{\mu 0}\omega^{1}_{\nu}+\sigma_{\mu 1}\omega^{0}_{\nu}$$

Now I would need to set values to all possibilities of the $\mu$ $\nu$ components to and show if it is non-zero or zero? I got it right?

Comment: No, it only needs the first two terms. What I meant was such anti/symmetric tensors have a few degrees of freedom in terms of which you can compute $(\sigma\omega)_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: I can see it now, if I get the $$00$$ component, I could still have a term like:

$$\sigma_{0\beta}\omega^{\beta}_{0}=\sigma_{00}g_{\gamma 0}\omega^{0\gamma}+...$$

If I expand the $\gamma$, I still could get non-zero therms from this first one. Nice, thank you!